# How to set background color of HorizontalHeaderView Qt QML Quick Controls 2 (Qt6.5)

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

How is the background color of a HorizontalHeaderView within a TableView to be set?

My goal is a table where the heading has a dark background, and a bright text color.

possible layout: [image]

I neither managed to get it via palette, nor via a background property.

The only way I've seen was with a stack of colored rects behind the delegates, while there the size never matched the table size.
And if I simply put a rect behind the header delegates, the top bar never becomes solid because of the columnSpacing.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

...

    TableView {
        id: myTable
        anchors { fill: parent; topMargin: horizontalHeader.height }
        columnSpacing: 4; rowSpacing: 4
        implicitHeight: parent.height
        implicitWidth: parent.width

        model: SuperCarModel {}

        ...
    }    

    HorizontalHeaderView {
        id: horizontalHeader
        syncView: myTable
        anchors.left: myTable.left
        anchors.top: myTable.top
        clip: true

        delegate: Item {
            implicitHeight: delegateLabel.implicitHeight
            implicitWidth: delegateLabel.implicitWidth
            Label {
                id: delegateLabel
                text: model.display
                font.bold: true
                color: palette.buttonText
                padding: 4
                leftPadding: 4
            }
            Rectangle {
                anchors.left: delegateLabel.left
                anchors.top: delegateLabel.top
                anchors.bottom: delegateLabel.bottom
                color: "#aaa"
                z: delegateLabel.z - 1
            }
        }
```

Would expect a background property in the headerView or perhaps a palette entry like

```
palette.background: "black"
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a shot in the dark, as it is pulled from a 5.15 application. Hopefully, it is what you need.
The header bar is defined separately, so its colors are also defined separately. The final result looks like this:

[image]

The ListView is defined as so:

```
        ListView {
            model: eventLog
            delegate: EventRow{}
            header: EventHeader{}
            headerPositioning: ListView.OverlayHeader
            clip: true
            focus: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: parent.borderSize+3
            anchors.rightMargin: parent.borderSize-2
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
                id: scrollbar
                policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
                width: parent.width/70
                background: Rectangle {
                    radius: width / 2
                }
            }

            onCountChanged: Qt.callLater(positionViewAtEnd)
        }
```

Notice that *delegate:* and *header:* are separate components, and here is how "EventHeader" and "EventRow" are defined:

```
component EventHeader: Row {
    property var titles: [ "Time", "Net-Frame", "Type", "Node", "Code" , "Description" ]
    property var widths: [ 235, 140, 65, 65, 65, 651 ]
    height: 30
    width: ListView.view.width//-scrollbar.width-3
    z: 2

    Repeater {
        model: widths.length
        HeaderField { width: widths[index]; text: titles[index] }
    }
}

component EventRow: Row {
    width: ListView.view.width      //-scrollbar.width-3
    height: 30
    
    EventField {
        width: 235
        text: timeStamp
    }
    EventField {
        width: 140
        text: netFrame
    }
    EventField {
        width: 65
        text: severity
    }
    EventField {
        width: 65
        text: node
    }
    EventField {
        width: 65
        text: code
    }
    EventField {
        width: 651
        text: description
        horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignLeft
    }
}
```

Sorry for the overuse of *component*. Note that the column widths are also defined separately, and therefore need to match.

For both the header and the data, the fields inside each row are also components, *HeaderField* and *EventField*.

```
component EventField: Label {
    height: parent.height
    leftPadding: 5
    rightPadding: leftPadding
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    font.pixelSize: 24
    font.capitalization: Font.MixedCase
    color: ( severity === "Info" ) ? "blue" : (severity === "Warn" ) ? "orange" : "red" ;
    background: Rectangle {
        border.width: 1
        border.color: "dimgrey"
    }
}

component HeaderField: Label {
    height: parent.height
    leftPadding: 5
    rightPadding: leftPadding
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    font.pixelSize: 24
    font.capitalization: Font.MixedCase
    font.family: "Arial"
    color: "black"
    background: Rectangle {
        border.width: 1
        border.color: "dimgrey"
        color: "#E7E7E7"
    }
}
```

Each field has a *background:*, so the border, fill and font colors can be set on a per-field basis. This code only does it on a per-row basis.

It may be more complicated than what you wanted. It also might be a little different in version 6.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your detailed answer. 
It's not directly what I expected, but an interesting solution to build the table on top of a listview. 
I'm starting to get the feeling that Qt Quick is still too much under development?!

Comment: Hi Cody. My example tries to adhere to the Model–view–controller paradigm, where the data is in a some invisible data model, and what you can see is in a view of that data model. Yes, it is more complicated than what you probably need, but QML's Model-view implementation is good at solving more complicated UI tasks.

Comment: Also, this example uses "components", whereas the code could have simply been inline. It's a matter of taste on which is more readable.